# Javascript: Por qué no soy capaz de detectar que tecla he pulsado?

Tags: javascript

Tengo este código:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event){
        var Tecla_Presionada = event.keyCode;
        if Tecla_Presionada == 87 {
          document.getElementById('Resultado').innerHTML = "Hola";
        }
      }
```

```html
<span id="Resultado"></span>
```

En teoría, el span debería cambiar de contenido cuando pulsase la tecla "w", que tiene el keyCode = 87, pero no funciona.

Alguien sabe si me estoy saltando algún paso, o si hay algún error de cualquier tipo?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Te faltan unos paréntesis en el `if`. Si miras la consola de JS verás que te da un error de sintaxis. No sé si esto debería considerarse un fallo tipográfico o no.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro ¿por qué no? Se sobreentiende que es un error de sintaxis.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía Ok, entonces lo pongo como respuesta. No sabía si responder o votar por cerrar.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía dejé [en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38519736#38519736) mi opinión sobre estos casos.

Answer (score 0):

Haz debug del código para localizar el fallo, por ejemplo, saber si entra a la función, si el evento te devuelve un código de tecla, si entras al condicional...

```
  document.onkeydown = function(event) {
    console.log( "Tecla pulsada" );

    var Tecla_Presionada = event.keyCode;
    console.log( "Código tecla: " + Tecla_Presionada );

    if (Tecla_Presionada == 87) {
      console.log( "Cumplida condición..." );
      document.getElementById('Resultado').innerHTML = "Hola";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu ejemplo esta bien (apartando los paréntesis que ya coloque) solo te falta hacer foco en la ventana donde se ejecuta el `script`.

Ejemplo:

```js
document.onkeydown = function(event) {
 var Tecla_Presionada = event.keyCode;
 if ( Tecla_Presionada == 87 ) {
  document.getElementById('Resultado').innerHTML = "Hola";
 }
}
window.focus();
```

```html
<span id="Resultado"></span>
```